# vsftpd: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_mariadb_mtr.so)

Tags: debian, mariadb, pam, vsftpd

I try to configure VSFTPD with MariaDB. I would like use PAM for more simplicity and i got this error in auth.log :

> vsftpd: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_mariadb_mtr.so): /lib/security/pam_mariadb_mtr.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I dont find how i can obtain this file `pam_mariadb_mtr.so` for **MariaDB 5.5.34**.

I have read the [official documentation about PAM authentication on MariaDB's website](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/pam-authentication-plugin/) but nothing about how to get this file :(

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok,

i'm going wrong. I have installed `libpam-mysql` package and now the problem is solved.